# How to fix "failed to locate @require file ~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors.styl"

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, stylus

I'm using Nuxt and Vuetify version 1.5.6, and want to upgrade Vuetify to version 2.0.1. After upgrading Vuetify to version 2.0.1, I received an error like this:

> ERROR  in ./assets/style/app.styl
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/stylus-loader/index.js)
>
> Error: /var/www/html/nuxt/my-project/assets/style/app.styl:3:10
>
> 1| // Import and define Vuetify color theme
>
> 2| // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/colors
>
> 3| @require '~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors'
>
> failed to locate @require file ~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors.styl

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix that error?

I have tried some fixes and still get an error.

Here is my `app.style`:

```
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_colors'
$theme := {
  primary:     $blue.darken-2
  accent:      $blue.accent-2
  secondary:   $grey.lighten-1
  info:        $blue.lighten-1
  warning:     $amber.darken-2
  error:       $red.accent-4
  success:     $green.lighten-2
}

// Import Vuetify styling
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'

.page
  @extend .fade-transition
```

Comment: The 2.0 release includes moving from Stylus to Sass. Color documentation is here ~ https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors

Comment: @Phil so what should i do now , there is an error when im update the version?

Comment: I suggest you consult the rather lengthy [upgrade guide](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0#user-content-upgrade-guide). It doesn't look like you can just drop in version 2 without making some drastic changes to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify no longer uses Stylus in version 2.x. You will need to manually copy all the stylus files into your project (which can be done from your `node_modules`) if you still want to use their color schemes. This will require you to have a Stylus loader in webpack. Or you can migrate to SASS and utilize their color schemes and variables; this is a pain but if you are sticking with Vuetify probably a good choice. Of course you could combine these two methods and do a gradual migration.

Comment: how to migrate from stylus to sass ?

Comment: the issue or Vuetify 2.x no longer using stylus is not well documented. Can you please give an example of how to migrate stylus to sass? thank you!

Comment: try the vuetify discord channel, you can probably get some more specific help there.
https://discordapp.com/channels/340160225338195969/361889521815519233